# Div content float left 100% when a hide a module right float right Joomla

Tags: html, css, joomla

I cant solve. I have my content in a float left css with:

```
float: left;
height: auto;
margin: 0px 22px;
clear: none;
min-width: 66.768799%;
max-width:100%;
width:0;
```

overflow: auto;

and my right module css

```
float: right;
height: auto;
margin: 0px 15px 0px 0px;
clear: none;
width: 28.461538%;
```

overflow: auto;

they are inside of a wrapper

```
float: none;
height: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-top: 0px;
clear: none;
width: 100%;
max-width: 1300px;
margin-right: auto;
background-color:
```

the case is when I hide a module right the content cant expant 100%, still in 66%

```css
#content {
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0px 22px;
    clear: none;
    min-width: 66.768799%;
 max-width:100%;
 width:0;
    overflow: auto;
}
#right_module {
    float: right;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0px 15px 0px 0px;
    clear: none;
    width: 28.461538%;
    overflow: auto;
}
#wrapper {
    float: none;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    clear: none;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1300px;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: rgb(226, 208, 168);
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">Curabitur venenatis vehicula mattis. Nunc eleifend consectetur odio sit amet viverra. Ut euismod ligula eu tellus interdum mattis ac eu nulla. Phasellus cursus, lacus quis convallis aliquet, dolor urna ullamcorper mi, eget dapibus velit est vitae nisi. Aliquam erat nulla, sodales at imperdiet vitae, convallis vel dui.</div>
  <div id="right_module">Nunc eleifend consectetur odio sit amet viverra. Phasellus cursus, lacus quis convallis aliquet, dolor urna ullamcorper mi, eget dapibus velit est vitae nisi. Aliquam erat nulla, sodales at imperdiet vitae, convallis vel dui. Ut euismod ligula eu tellus interdum mattis ac eu nulla. </div>
</div>
```

rgb(226, 208, 168);
    padding: 10px;

the case is when I hide a module right the content cant expant 100%, still in 66%. Please help my head in apoint exploit

Comment: Are you hiding the right_module with javascript/jquery?

Comment: Did you see my solution below? If this solved your problem, please mark as answered!

Answer (score 0):

Remove `width: 0;` from `#content {` selector.